# How do I make it so that the bot only responds to direct pings or replies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make it so that the bot only responds to direct pings or replies.

I tried this:

```
if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
```

But if I use that, the bot will also respond to @everyone and @here, which I don't want. It must be a direct ping specifically for the bot. Replying to the bot should also work.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if your bot is in the message [mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions) list:

```py
if client.user in message.mentions:
    pass
```

Comment: Will it work for replies?

Comment: Yes, it works with replies

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle those is:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    for mention in message.mentions:
        if isinstance(mention, discord.Role):
            # Handle role mention
            pass
        elif isinstance(mention, discord.User) or isinstance(mention, discord.Member):
            # Handle user mention
            pass
        elif isinstance(mention, discord.TextChannel) or isinstance(mention, discord.VoiceChannel) or isinstance(mention, discord.CategoryChannel):
            # Handle channel mention
            pass
```

API reference: [Mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions)

Answer (score -3):

you could either `if client.user.mentioned_in(message) and if message != "@everyone":`

you can add another and for @here
you could also imbed another if statement

```
if client.user.mentioned_in(message):

if message != "@everyone"
```

another if statement could be added for @here
hope this helps!

`

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow community. Please provide a better [improved] answer to the question. Your code seems to be very broad and according to the API reference https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.mentions this is not the best route to dealing with mentions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).